# Variable updated in controller but not updated in HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to get a better handle on Angular.js.
As stated in the title, I have a variable in a controller which changes values when called by a member function, however the update is not pushed to the HTML.

Here is my code:

### HTML

```
<div class="row" id="copyMessage" ng-controller="swatchController as swatchCtrl" ng-    click="swatchCtrl.message()">
        <h1>{{swatchCtrl.inactive}}</h1> 
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
app.controller('swatchController', function(){
    this.inactive = true; //This is the variable whose value I want to change

    this.message = function(){ //This function is called in my HTML 
        this.inactive = false; 
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.inactive = true;
            alert(this.inactive); //Spits out true as expected but this value is not pushed to HTML
        }, 2000);           
    };
});
```

Again, the problem here is that swatchCtrl.inactive remains as false even after the message() function has been called onclick. Any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `$timeout` so the callback initiates a digest cycle. Also check that `this` refers to the controller in all instances.

Comment: I would inject `$scope` into the controller and use `$scope` instead of `this` (in your code, `this` inside the `setTimeout` will not be what you expect). Also, instead of using `setTimeout`, `$timeout` is usually recommended (you need to inject that too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your code to this should work:

```
app.controller('swatchController', function($timeout){
    var _this = this;

    this.inactive = true; //This is the variable whose value I want to change

    this.message = function(){ //This function is called in my HTML 
        this.inactive = false; 
        $timeout(function(){
            _this.inactive = true;
            alert(_this.inactive); //Spits out true as expected but this value is not pushed to HTML
        }, 2000);           
    };
});
```

You can't use the `this` keyboard inside the timeout callback as it refers to something else. You should also use Angular's `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` so that Angular knows to update the DOM when it is done.

Comment: Using $timeout and _this did the trick.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of how `this` works in Javascript.  Change to this instead:

```
app.controller('swatchController', function($timeout){
    var self = this;

    this.inactive = true; //This is the variable whose value I want to change

    this.message = function(){ //This function is called in my HTML 
        this.inactive = false; 
        $timeout(function(){
            self.inactive = true;
            alert(self.inactive); //Spits out true as expected but this value is not pushed to HTML
        }, 2000);           
    };
});
```

The value of `this` changes in Javascript depending on the execution context, so in your example, `this` inside the `timeout` is no longer representative of the controller, but instead it refers to the global scope (`Window`).

Using closures and saving off the reference to `this` when the controller loads is how you get around this problem.